# Import xml in another xml with Python ElementTree parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Is it possible to load an xml file which imports another xml file with Python ElementTree.parse ?

For example:
I have file test.xml which contains:

```
<TestXml>
    <!DOCTYPE doc [
        <!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "test_1.xml">
    ]>
</TestXml>
```

and I also have test_1.xml which contains:

```
<test>it works!</test>
```

and I want to load test.xml in my python script:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

a = parse('test.xml')

print a.find('test').text
```

and I expect it to output:

```
it works!
```

but instead I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/depot/WIP/olex/Python/test/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = parse('test.xml')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 6
```

Does somebody know what am I doing wrong or it is just impossible to load such a xml file for python ElementTree parser ?

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem you are having is that your xml is malformed. Your `DOCTYPE` declaration should not be inside your root element. Rather, it should precede your root element:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
        <!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "test_1.xml">
    ]>
<TestXml>
 some content . . .
</TestXml>
```

That said, you will face a larger problem once you solve that issue. How do you use Python to parse the DOCTYPE declaration? Should you use the `xml` module, the `lxml` module, or the `bs4` module?

That's a tough question. From what I have seen, people have (recently) had to do dtd parsing themselves. See the SO threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421588/dtd-parser-for-django-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758752/parser-for-xml-dtd-file/22932501#22932501) for some possible leads.